# comparing surface integral and volume integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: I have a question. Suppose $f$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ ($N>1$). Is it true that 
$$\int_{\partial B(x,r)}|f|d\sigma\leq\int_{B(x,r)}|f|d\lambda?$$ Why? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That inequality cannot hold for all functions $f$ (we may assume $f\ge 0$ without loss of generality, by the way).

To wit, let us examine how the inequality reacts to a change of scale $r\mapsto \lambda r$ where $\lambda >0$. We have 
$$
\int_{\partial B(0, \lambda r) }f(y)\, \sigma(dy) = \lambda^{N-1} \int_{\partial B(0, r)} f(\lambda y')\, \sigma(dy'), $$
and
$$
\int_{B(0, \lambda r)} f(y)\, dy = \lambda^{N} \int_{B(0, r)} f(\lambda y')\, dy'. $$
So, setting $f_\lambda(y)=f(\lambda y)$ and assuming that the inequality holds true we have 
$$\tag{!!}\int_{\partial B(0, r)} f_\lambda\,d\sigma \le \lambda \int_{B(0, r)}f_\lambda\, dV.$$ 
This inequality manifestly fails for any $f$ that is homogeneous of any degree, that is, any $f$ such that 
$$f_\lambda(y)=\lambda^\alpha f(y), $$
for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, in this case inequality (!!) reduces to 
$$C_f\le \lambda, $$ 
where $C_f$ is a constant depending only on $f$ and not on $\lambda$. This is absurd as $\lambda > 0$ is a free parameter that can be shrunk to $0$.

From a physicist's point of view, that inequality cannot hold because you are trying to compare two quantities that have different dimensions.

Comment: How about $f=\chi_{\partial B(x,r)}$?;)